# How to plot two groups of values?

Tags: r, plot, error-handling, grouping

These are my sets of four mean values:

```
meanf1hindi = c(253, 297, 377, 426, 476, 518, 560, 620, 657, 697)
meanf2hindi = c(850, 887, 1017, 1080, 1197, 1342, 1694, 1820, 2265)
meanf1tamil = c(260, 304, 390, 435, 483, 527, 563, 628, 670, 704)
meanf2tamil = c(891, 826, 1018, 1068, 1188, 1355, 1709, 1834, 1976, 2303)
```

I would like to make a linear graph of *meanf1hindi* and *meanf2hindi* together, and do the same with *meanf1tamil* and *meanf2tamil*.

This is what I did so far, and don't know how to proceed further:

```
plot(meanf1hindi, meanf2hindi)
```

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Comment: `meanf1hindi` contains 10 values and `meanf2hindi` contains 9 values. `plot(mean1hindi, meanf2hindi` assumes that the each value of `meanf1hindi` correspondence to the x-axis value, and each value of `meanf2hindi` correspondence to the y-axis value, of each point. Since the length is different, the function do not know how to deal with it, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the `length` differs for your vectors. What you can do is make the two vectors' length the same by removing one value for the longer vector in this case remove one value of `meanf1hindi` by doing this:

```
> length(meanf1hindi)
[1] 10
> length(meanf2hindi)
[1] 9
plot(meanf1hindi[-1], meanf2hindi)
```

Output:

[image]